# WPF Convert Checkbox.IsChecked to int or string 1 or 0

Tags: c#, wpf

So for Winforms its very easy to do this:

```
streamWriter.WriteLine(this.checkbox1.Checked ? "1" : "0");
```

but how I can do this in WPF ?
I have to use ".IsChecked" and then i get the Message, that I can't convert bool? into bool.

I just tried:

```
streamWriter.WriteLine(this.checkbox1.IsChecked ? "1" : "0");
```

which doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In WPF `Checkbox.IsChecked` is of `Nullable` type. So you would have to modify your code to:

```
streamWriter.WriteLine((this.checkbox1.IsChecked == true) ? "1" : "0");
```

Note: If you see `?` after a `DataType` like: `bool? abc`, then it means `abc` can have `null` as its value, when by default a `bool` variable does not accept `null` as value.

Examples:

For `int` datatype:

```
int variable = 0; //correct
int variable = null; //incorrect
int? variable = null; //correct
int? variable = 1; //correct
```

For `bool` datatype:

```
bool mybool = false; //correct
bool mybool = null; //incorrect
bool? mybool = null; //correct
bool? mybool = true; //correct
```

Also in `bool? mybool = true;` and `int? variable = 1;`, if you further want to retrieve the values of these variable as a proper `bool` or `int`, you would have to *convert* them using 
`Convert.ToBoolean`, `Convert.ToInt32` respectively.

Comment: Ah okay. Are all bool arguments in WPF nullable?

Comment: No as I said, if a `Datatype` is postfixed using `?` for a variable. It would be able to store `null` also. By default `bool`, `int` etc doesn't allow `null` to be stored.

Comment: @OJean `IsChecked` returns a `bool?` because that's how the property is designed. Not everything in WPF is designed this way. See my answer.

Comment: @OJean I've modified my answer for a better understanding. Kindly check it

Comment: I guess i understand it. Thank you guys for helping.

Answer (score 1):

`CheckBox` inherits the `IsChecked` from `ToggleButton`. `ToggleButton` is not designed to "must either be checked or unchecked". A `ToggleButton` is just something you can toggle. With checkboxes, `IsChecked` can be null if you turn `IsThreeStates` on.

Then you must decide what happens when the checkbox is in the third state. Do you want it to be a 1 or 0?

```
streamWriter.WriteLine((this.checkbox1.IsChecked ?? false) ? "1" : "0");
                                                    ^^^^^
```

//                                          replace this with true if you want the third state to be "1"

If you did not turn `IsThreeStates` on, then you can write either `true` or `false` after `??`.

Comment: " I am not sure whether it will be in the state of "neither checked nor unchecked" - Actually WPF Checkbox can be in this state `<CheckBox IsThreeState="True"/>` so `Null` value is used for the third state.

Comment: @Mitya Thanks for the info. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

Checkbox is of nullable type. In addition, use the `click` event in xaml. Don't forget to call the `Close()` method after writing the file.